# WCF netTcpBinding Unsecured fault, System Time not synchronized with Server

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, nettcpbinding

I have the following netTcpBinding in my WCF project:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTcpBindingConf" closeTimeout="00:11:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="100" openTimeout="00:20:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:15:00"/>
      <!--<security mode="None"></security>-->
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I have deployed the service as Window Azure Worker Role and defined the certificates to it (also checked that the certificates are correctly installed on the worker role VM).

When my client application tries to connect to the service I get "Unsecured fault, System Time not synchronized with Server".

From what I've read, I found something about setting clock skew - but it doesn't seem to have that kind of definition in netTcpBinding - and I couldn't find information about it.

How can I make the client connect securely?

Comment: have you made sure the clock on your local box is set correctly and on the correct timezone?

Comment: @iamkrillin Yes. The clock on my machine (client) is correct. And the clock on the WorkerRole, I can't change - because each time the WrokerRole will start it will reset - also I'm pretty sure that Microsoft configures it correctly.

Comment: did you try this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738468%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @iamkrillin - thanks. but it didn't mentioned anything about netTcpBinding. I tried adding customBinding like they suggested (only changing to tcpTransport) - but it didn't work.